# How to access same List in Class from multiple .cs files?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

A fairly simple question I guess.. I'm trying to access a list in a public Class (just an .CS file in my project.).

In one .xaml.cs I access the class by using

```
DataClass dataClass = new DataClass();
```

When I try to access it in the other .xaml.cs file I used DataClass dataClass = new DataClass(); again. Of course this creates a NEW class (so all the information that is stored inside is not there.

How can I access the Class without creating a new one?

Kind regards,
Niels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the list a [**static data member**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in the DataClass and make methods to access it from other classes. Static data member is a shared copy for all the instance of that class. You can make it Concurrent list if the list is supposed to be accessed by different threads using lock. You can use [**ConcurrentBag**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) for multi-threaded environment. It worth reading [**singleton pattern**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) that is often used in similar situations.

```
 public class DataClass 
 { 
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    private static DataClass instance; 
    private DataClass() { }
    public static DataClass Instance 
    {
        get 
        {
            if(instance==null) 
            { 
                instance = new DataClass(); 
            } 
             return instance; 
        } 
    }  
}

public class Class1
{
     public void SetValue(string str)
     {
         DataClass ds = DataClass.Instance;
         ds.Timestamp  = "value1";
     }
}

public class Class2
{
     public string GetValue(string str)
     {
         DataClass ds = DataClass.Instance;
         return ds.Timestamp;
     }
}


Class1 c1 = new Class1();
c1.SetValue("hello");
Class2 c2 = new Class2();
string value = c2.GetValue();
```

Comment: this can add concurrency and race condition problems

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried using a Singleton pattern but it doesn't seem to work. This is my code right now:


DataClass xmlClass = new DataClass();
xmlClass.Timestamp = "15-08-2012";


public class DataClass
{
        public string Timestamp { get; set; }
}

So how could I use the Singleton pattern in here?

Comment: You might have missed something, give it a try again after reading the pattern implementation carefully. For understanding just make this list static and access it by class instead of instance of your class. DataClass.YourListName[0] = something; and access in other class.

Comment: public class DataClass 
{ 
 public string Timestamp { get; set; } 

 private static DataClass instance;

 private DataClass()
 {
 } 

 public static DataClass Instance
 {
   get
   {
     if(instance==null)
     {
       instance = new DataClass();
     }
     return instance;
   }
 }

}

Comment: Your care creating instance of DataClass, you should not create instance of DataClass rather call Instance method to get its instance. make the construtor private.

Comment: @Adil Hmm I think I'm not following you guys anymore... Can you provide a sample?

Comment: Updated my answer have a look

Comment: `DataClass.Instance` is a property but you're calling it like a method.

Answer (score 0):

There is pattern named Singleton. I guess it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a read only property which instantiates a new instance upon first access like so:

```
private DataClass dataClass;
public DataClass DataClass
{
    get
    {
        if(dataClass  == null)
        {
             dataClass = new DataClass();
        }
        return dataClass;
    }
}
```